# Correct syntax for defining custom trigger with OrFinally in Apache Beam in Python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to define a custom trigger for a sliding window that triggers repeatedly for every element, but also triggers finally at the end of the watermark. I've looked around documentation for almost an hour now but have yet to find any example :(.

```
        | beam.WindowInto(
            beam.window.SlidingWindows(60, 10),
            trigger= Repeatedly(
                (AfterCount(1), OrFinally(AfterWatermark()))
            ),
            accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
        )
```

This is what I'm trying right now and clearly this doesn't work but I am extremely lost in what the correct syntax is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try changing the trigger like below and see

```
trigger=OrFinally(Repeatedly(AfterCount(1)), AfterWatermark()),
accumulation_mode=beam.transforms.trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Error: `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: I tried something like:

`trigger=OrFinally(Repeatedly(AfterCount(1)), AfterWatermark())`

And this runs without throwing an error, but is this achieving what we expect? Looking at the source code (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/transforms/trigger.py#L799) it looks like OrFinally() expects some iterable of triggers but I'm not sure what ordering it expects the triggers in. From what it looks like, the second trigger is the trigger that is called finally, but I'm not too sure. Just started working with Beam yesterday :)

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can take a look, you would need a Repeated trigger to keep triggering for different events. The AfterAny will ensure that if there are more than 1 trigger if anyone is satisfied it will run. And OrFinally will ensure that once it is run the trigger stops. For the usecase scenario the trigger will run `Repeatedly` for every 1 row till finally the window closes. Hope that helps and welcome to Beam :)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry, I'm still having trouble getting your example to work. It looks like the OrFinally function takes in more than one argument and Python is giving me a syntax error.

So, if I am understanding correctly, when the orFinally() condition is satisfied, then the Repeating trigger never fires again. In the case of a sliding window, does this mean that only one of the sliding windows will fire due to the AfterWatermark() and once that happens, no more windows will be emitted?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry about that I don't code that much in Python but the trigger definition that you have used is correct. If you look at `OrFinally` it extends `AfterAny`. The `AfterAny` trigger fires when any sub-trigger fires and finishes when any sub-trigger finishes. In this case it will finish at the end of the Watermark for a window. Each sliding window will have its own watermark and own window closure. A window can have multiple panes which is what the first trigger will emit through the Repeated trigger. Hope it was clear.

Comment: No worries, thanks that makes a lot of sense. Cheers :)